Convert Excel formula to Power Query (if countifs)
I have an excel formula in column D below using this formula.
=IF(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,"Y")>0,"Y","N")

How can I do the same thing in power query? I understand that using group by does the job on countifs but how can I bring it all together as a new column in Power query?


To help you get more help try reading this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Assuming your data is in a table called Table1 you could do this
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    grouped = 
    let
        // unnecessary duplication Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
        #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Category", "Used?"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [ID=number, Category=text, #"Used?"=text, Category used=text, Column1=number]}}),
        #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([#"Used?"] = "Y")),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Category Used", each "Y"),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Count", "Used?"})
    in
        #"Removed Columns",
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Category"}, #"grouped", {"Category"}, "grouped", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded grouped" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "grouped", {"Category Used"}, {"Category Used"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded grouped",null,"N",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Category Used"})

in
    #"Replaced Value"

Source is the original table
grouped is that table grouped by Used? and then filtered for just the 'Y'
After that I did a left outer join between Source and grouped which returns either 'Y' or null. Then just replace the null with 'N'
Alternatively you could make grouped a function and add a column that returns that value

Thank you, this works great. I need to repeat this for other columns in my power query but every time I use this query it sources back to the orginal woorkbook and so overwrites any previous steps. How can I write this so that it is the next step in a query so I can keep repeating for different additional columns?

I'm not really getting what you mean. Describe what you are trying to do with another column, or post the code that is "overwriting" previous steps

Quick cheat way - use Group By with Max...

And then expand "Rows".

Or you can do this:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  grouped = Table.Group(Source, {"Category"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type nullable table[ID = any, Used = any]}}),
  countUsed = Table.AddColumn(grouped, "Count", each List.Count(List.Select([Grouped][Used], each _="Y"))),
  IsUsed = Table.AddColumn(countUsed, "Category Used", each if [Count] > 0 then "Y" else "N"),
  expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(IsUsed, "Grouped", {"ID", "Used"}, {"ID", "Used"})

in
  expanded


